# How to change the information of a text box inside a layout using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layouts, parameters, text

I have a `layout` in which there are several text boxes. When I click on one of the text boxes, a window appears with several parameters, for instance the name of the text box:

[image]

Imagine that I have two of those text boxes, `Title_A` and `Title_B`, for which I want to be able to change parts of the text, namely the years, via ArcPy. For example, I would like to be able to change 2015 and 2020 to 2016 and 2021 respectively, by means of an Arcpy script. So:
`change in temperature 2015 - 2020` becomes `change in temperature 2016 - 2021`.

What would be the most convenient way to change parts of text boxes in the layout by means of an ArcPy script in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TextElement](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/textelement-class.htm) item, to identify and change based on item names:

```py
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\Projects\YosemiteNP\Yosemite.aprx")
for lyt in aprx.listLayouts():
    for elm in lyt.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT"):
        if elm.text == "2013":
            elm.text = "2014"
aprx.save()
del aprx
```